# Why doesn't a 58mm diameter filter fit on EF 50mm f/1.4?

Tags: canon, filters

I have bought a HOYA circular polarizer filter 58mm (CIR-PL) for the Canon EF 50mm f1.4 (said to be 58mm filter size). But the filter doesn't fit. Did I miss something? It doesn't even fit on a 18-55 kit lens (Yeah I know that filter isn't useful on that lens....but still).

Comment: Why do you say the polarizer isn't useful on the kit lens?  Because you need to re-rotate the filter every time you change focus?  If you're shooting any sort of still life, that really shouldn't be a problem: with either lens you're going to focus first, then adjust the polarizer.  Or did you have some other reason in mind?

Comment: Perhaps you could describe the way it fails to fit: filter diameter too large/small or threads not mating up, etc.

Comment: @drewbenn Yeah, it is the re-rotaing problem which is been mentioned in a thread here.

Comment: @Lyman, as mentioned below, it was a mistake from my side (due to inexperience, of course).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I happen to own the exact same model of lens and filter, and they do fit.
Check the image to see if your equipment differs in any way, or if you are trying to attach it in any other way:

[image]

Comment: ZOMG! Thanks for the picture. I was of course trying to make it fit in a wrong way :-)

Answer (score 14):

It should fit.

Could you be attempting to screw it backwards or on the wrong side? One side has the thread to match your lens, the other (if there is one) is meant to screw another filter.

Comment: Yeah. I was doing it in reverse. I think my brain was polarized.

Answer (score 1):

Mine (same lens and filter) works just fine BUT, its very picky about initially threading the filter onto the lens mount, the thread tolerances are very close. If you can't get it to screw on properly try another filter. If that won't thread properly get a magnifying glass and check both the lens and the filter threads to see if they're damaged/bent from cross-threading. If the lens mount has been crosstreaded you may be SOL for using filters on that lens.